# IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0.2 install failing at "Waiting for Cloudant to Start"

Tags: cloudant, ibm-cloud-private

IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0.2 ce install is failing at "Waiting for Cloudant to Start", it is a multinode cluster with CentOS 7.2, docker version 17.09 running.
I have One common boot and master node, One worker node and One proxy node. I have checked the hardware requirements and assigned more that 151GB storage on all nodes. I have also pulled the icp-datastore locally.

Can anyone please help with suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should edit cloudant deployment and increase readiness timeout, so the platform can take its time to rebuild the database. can be achieved using kubectl (kubectl edit deploy xxxx) or using ICP console

Comment: Thanks for the reply, editing the cloudant deployment and increasing readiness timeout did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the following:

1. Are you using firewall enabled? Always ensure the correct state before install even after an uninstall.
2. Are you using IPsec enabled? Try to install with IPsec disabled.
3. Ensure you're disabling SElinux every time you run the install.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I did disable firewall, IPsec is not enabled. I have disabled Selinux as well. Install continues to fail.